# Ktor IO client, how to prevent multiple refreshTokens invocation

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

I have implemented `Auth` feature with `bearer` token. Here is my `refreshTokens` implementation

```
refreshTokens {
    val fullUrl = "$baseUrl/auth/token:refresh"
    val refreshToken = preference.get(PreferenceKeys.REFRESH_TOKEN.key)
    val authData = tokenClient.post<AuthResponse>(fullUrl) {
        body = AuthResponse(null, refreshToken)
        header(HttpHeaders.ContentType, ContentType.Application.Json)}
    BearerTokens(
        accessToken = authData.accessToken ?: "",
        refreshToken = authData.refreshToken ?: "")
}
```

and it works as expected, if only one request has been made, but if multiple requests get 401 `UnAuthorized` error at a same time, this callback fires multiple times. Are there any locking mechanisms, that I should implement to prevent mutiple token refreshing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Due to version `2.0.0-beta-1` they create a queue for requests those needed to refresh token
see this link as a new feature:

https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta-1

and this as issue number:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-3325